# Export in Mathematica 9 vs Mathematica 10

Tags: export, bugs

**Bug introduced in 10.0 and fixed in 10.0.2**

---

I want to export a list of complex numbers as follows:

```
uu=1.0+0.0I//FortranForm
Export["file.in", Flatten[{uu}], "Table"];
```

The file (`file.in`) contains the following:

Version 9:

```
(1.,0.)
```

Version 10:

```
Complex(1.,0.)
```

I want the output of V9, but I need to use V10. How could I get the same output as in V9, using V10?

Comment: Fixed in version 10.0.2 and later.

Comment: @ilian thank you for commenting on all of these questions. May I suggest that if you are satisfied that something is a bug, that you tag the question as such? This will make it easier to find later on.

Comment: @Oleksandr Sure, I usually do this kind of edit but evidently can also forget to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ilian mentioned that this is fixed in newer version of Mathematica, but if you are not able to update, the following helper function may be of help:

```
toFor[c_] := "(" <> ToString[Re[c]] <> "," <> ToString[Im[c]] <> ")"

numbers = RandomComplex[10 + 10 I, 100];
Export["file.in", toFor /@ numbers, "Table"]
```

This exports a list of numbers in the format indicated above, separated by carriage returns/new lines:

```
(9.11984,3.81308)
(7.10358,4.19413)
(8.21729,2.03658)
       ....
(7.74429,1.92139)
```

---

**UPDATE**

OP asked for a version with a specific output precision. Here is an amended version of the `toFor` function I proposed above in which one can specify the precision of the output.

```
toForPrec[c_, n_] := "(" <> ToString[SetPrecision[Re[c], n]] <> "," <> ToString[SetPrecision[Im[c], n]] <> ")"

newnumbers = RandomComplex[1/10 + 1/10 I, 100, WorkingPrecision -> 25];
Export["file.in", toForPrec[#, 15] & /@ newnumbers, "Table"]
```

... and the output now is:

```
(0.0172977041871843,0.0820605936318249)
(0.00278403446087895,0.0779569707654853)
(0.000249080445256925,0.0400488367614751)
                 .....
(0.0815582541497981,0.00541653436534768)
```

Comment: could you please edit your function such that it gives 17 digits after the first non-zero digit? That's what it did in V9. For example: 
13 (-0.009899126922473455,0.)
 14 (-0.010366600317484277,0.)
 15 (0.12651162321086884,0.)
 16 (-0.010897017057905087,0.)
 17 (-0.380165100325757,0.)

Comment: @Mencia I updated my answer: please see if it does what you want now.